# Competing CiviDiscount Automatic Discounts

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

We have a standard 10% discount on all of our events for members. On this specific event - we want to have a $5 flat discount for members.  The automatic 10% discount is still the only discount working.

Wordpress/Civi - Latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a standard discount - as in this example - all members get an automatic 10% discount towards any event - if you want to provide a different discount for a particular event to override the 10% discount - the following criteria must be met:

1. The other discount must be a percentage if the "standard"
   discount is a percentage. It must be a fixed discount if the standard discount is fixed.
2. The discount must be greater than the other discount. CiviDiscount will always choose the bigger discount.

Another approach is to not have a standard 10% discount on "any event", and instead manually add the events to the 10% discount code.  This is an added step we don't want to deal with. A feature I will request is that CiviDiscount provide an exclusion field, so we can select "Any Event" except:

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that CiviDiscount is taking the first available discount applicable for the specific event and ignoring the second (since only one can be used).  Have you tried removing this particular event from the list of allowed events for the 10% discount to see whether the $5 discount gets applied?

Comment: Thanks Leslie - I also answered the question.  The issue is that since our discount was in the form of a percentage, any greater discounts had to also be in a form of a percentage.